# How to check not exist field in document in vespa

Tags: vespa

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://xxxxxx/search/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "offset": 0,
    "hits": 60,
    "ranking.softtimeout.factor": 0.7,
    "ranking.profile": "default",
    "yql": "select id, origin_id from mt_challenge where best_score = \"null\";",
    "timeout": "1500ms",
    "request_timeout": 5
}'
```

best_score field is float type how to checkout all document with not exist best_score field

Answer (score 3):

Sorry but NaN/null values are not searchable so this is currently not supported. Using a default value at ingestion time which does not conflict with your real data can be used to work around this.

Comment: You can also modify your existing data using an "update where" to set a value on all documents currently having null, see https://docs.vespa.ai/en/reference/document-v1-api-reference.html#put

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! The dot product is an great suggestion

Comment: I use the vespa dump to checkout all docuement and filter by linux command 'grep -v' 
 to Pick out the one that meets the needs